# Multipath routing with only one interface

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I have two links that connect to Internet in my office network. One of the routers has ip **172.16.0.1** and the other has **172.16.0.3**. They connect to Internet using ppoe so they get an ip each time they connect.

I configured incomming traffic in a way that every that comes from the external IP will be routed to **172.16.0.120**. In 172.16.0.120 there is a webserver so I have load balancing and link failover.

The problem is that it seems I'm unable to tell **172.16.0.120** to route packets from the gateway they come from. And it seems that if I try one link or the other there is only one active (not really active, the packet are always sent through the same router). It depend on the route I add last.

What I do is something like this:

```
ip rule add from 172.16.0.1 table 1
ip rule add from 172.16.0.3 table 2
ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 dev eth1 scope link table 1
ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 dev eth1 scope link table 2
ip route add default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth1 table 1
ip route add default via 172.16.0.3 dev eth1 table 2
ip route add default scope global nexthop via 172.16.0.1 dev eth1 weight 1 nexthop via 172.16.0.3 dev eth1 weight 1
```

With this is supposed to send packets where they come from. But it's not working.

Maybe some iptables magic is needed here.